# Pressing tab takes me from subject to under the signature

Tags: thunderbird

I'm not sure if this is a bug or a configuration issue in Thunderbird 45.2.0 (latest).

When writing a message from an email account that comes with an html signature (external file), pressing the tab key on the keyboard to navigate from address to subject to email-body, moves the cursor from the subject line to *under* the signature.

Is there anything I can do, i.e. change a setting or change the html-signature, so that the cursor goes where it should?

Comment: Do you have some space above the email signature? If not, then it might be possible that the cursor is jumping to the last line (which is the email signature) in your case

Comment: I do, there is plenty of room above the double dash that starts the signature.